# Apply coupon code on Woocommerce checkout page and delay the update checkout contents

Tags: jquery, woocommerce, checkout

There is a option to add coupon code in my WooCommerce checkout page which is working perfectly. When customer apply a coupon, it applied successfully and update the checkout cart info by Ajax. The issue is when someone apply an invalid coupon which doesn't exist it shows the msg like "Coupon does not exist" and after a while that msg disappears because it is updating the cart contains area. How I can delay that update cart area in checkout so that my error msg stay longer.

I tried this without any luck

```js
jQuery(function($){
     $("body").on( 'click', ".checkout_coupon input[name='apply_coupon']", function(event, coupon){
          setTimeout( function(){
               jQuery("[name='update_checkout']").trigger("click");
          }, 25000);
    });
});
```

Comment: the event is called applied_coupon_in_checkout so you can hook on this event and do your logic. If you go to the sourcecode woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/checkout.js you will see wc_checkout_coupons.init(); there when you add or remove coupon triggers $( document.body ).trigger( 'update_checkout', { update_shipping_method: false } ); so its not click so your code doesnt make any sense. The delay its due to your server / executing the update. In slower servers may look like its "delayed" but its just taking time to reload. On stores that i make its instant. So there is no delay in the script.

Comment: Thanks @Snuffy to show me the way. I will definitely try this.